# Why GCloud Builds submit failing after creating image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I am learning deploying a pubsub service to run under `Cloud Run`, by following the guidelines given [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub)
Steps I followed are:

- Created a new project folder "myProject" in my local machine
- Added below files:
  `app.js`
  `index.js`
  `Dockerfile`
- Executed below command to ship the code

  ```
  gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/Project-ID/pubsub
  ```

It's mentioned in the tutorial document that

> Upon success, you should see a SUCCESS message containing the ID, creation time, and image name. The image is stored in Container Registry and can be re-used if desired.

But in my case it's returning with error: (Ref: screenshot)
[image: command failure with error]

I have verified the build logs, **"It's success"**
[image: Build logs]

So I thought to ignore this error and proceed with the next step to deploy the app by running the command:

```
gcloud run deploy sks-pubsub-cloudrun --image gcr.io/Project-ID/pubsub  --no-allow-unauthenticated
```

When I run this command it immediately asking to specify the region (26 is my choice) from the list.
Next it fails with error:

> Deploying container to Cloud Run service [sks-pubsub-cloudrun] in project [Project-ID] region [us-central1]
> Deploying new service... Cloud Run error: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable.
> Logs for this revision might contain more information.

As I am new to this GCP & Dockerizing services, not understanding this issue and unable to fix it. I researched many blogs and articles yet no proper solution for this error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Tried to run the container locally and it's failing with error.

I'm using VS Code IDE, and `"Cloud Code: Debug on Cloud Run Emulator"` to debug the code.

```
    Starting to debug the app using configuration `Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally` from .vscode/launch.json
To view more detailed logs, go to Output channel : "Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally - Detailed"
Dependency check started
Dependency check succeeded
Unpausing minikube
The minikube profile 'cloud-run-dev-internal' has been scheduled to stop automatically after exiting Cloud Code. To disable this on future deployments, set autoStop to false in your launch configuration d:\POC\promo_run_pubsub\.vscode\launch.json
Configuring minikube gcp-auth addon
Using GCP project 'Project-Id' with minikube gcp-auth
Failed to configure minikube gcp-auth addon. Your app might not be able to authenticate Google or GCP APIs it calls. The addon has been disabled. More details can be found in the detailed logs.






Update initiated
Deploy started
Deploy completed

Status check started
Resource pod/promo-run-pubsub-5d4cd64bf9-8pf4q status updated to In Progress
Resource deployment/promo-run-pubsub status updated to In Progress
Resource pod/promo-run-pubsub-5d4cd64bf9-8pf4q status updated to In Progress
Resource deployment/promo-run-pubsub status failed with waiting for rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
Status check failed

Update failed with error code STATUSCHECK_CONTAINER_TERMINATED
1/1 deployment(s) failed
Skaffold exited with code 1.
Cleaning up...
Finished clean up.
```

Comment: Please don't include screenshots. They're hosted on a 3rd-party service and will have a different lifetime than your question. They're not accessible. They make it difficult to copy relevant sections.

Comment: The build appears to have completed successfully. The container that was built does not run when Cloud Run tries to start it. The error "failed to start and listen" means that Cloud Run was unable to run your container. By default it expects it to expose a port (`PORT`) that defaults to `8080`. Try running the container locally to debug.

Comment: I used VS Code IDE and 'Cloud Code: Debug on Cloud Run Emulator' (container port is 8080) which is again failing with different error. Updated my question with local debug issue.

Comment: Cloud Shell includes Docker. Please try running `docker run --interactive --tty --rm --publish=8080:8080 gcr.io{your-image-name}` in one Cloud Shell instance and then, if it works (I think it won't) from another Cloud Shell session (or if you know how to do it port-forward) curl|browse the endpoint. I'm curious that your question references Pub/Sub. Is the container an HTTP service?

Comment: Let me run this command and will update you soon.
container responses with HTTP status code, so I guess it works as HTTP service.

Comment: Am I doing anything wrong here:
d:\POC\promo_run_pubsub>docker run --interactive --tty --rm --publish=8080:8080 gcr.io/Project-Id/sks-pubsub
docker: error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/create": open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: I checked the Detailed log and saw the same error message as in Cloud Build log: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"